# How can I Ctrl+select in StackOverflow?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox 44.0.2, I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Select</kbd> to select multiple words that are not at the same place.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX6Vf.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3ftu.png]

However, this shortcut key does not work on every website. 
When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Select</kbd> in SuperUser or in StackOverflow, I get the whole text area selected.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwrmo.png]

Does my configuration go wrong? Or was a new bug introduced in Firefox?

Comment: Close voters: the question isn't about usage of the site, so it isn't a question for Meta.  The fact the SU and SO are mentioned as examples of applicable sites doesn't make it off-topic.  It's about how to accomplish actions in a browser, which should be on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+select to select multiple words that are not at the same place works everywhere in Firefox 57 and later.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+select in Firefox 44.0.2 on my computer is able to select multiple words that are not at the same place after I click the `edit` hyperlink to edit the question or answer, and select multiple words in the edit pane. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+select doesn't work in my Firefox except for inside the editing pane, but this feature works everywhere in Firefox 57 and later.

Comment: Automatically selecting the whole element seems to be a really inconvenient feature of Firefox.